# Installshield on the second install returns -3 in silent mode

Tags: installshield

The scenario is when the same package being installed again in silent mode it returns -3(first time is 0) which is unwanted because the package will block other ones from proceeding.

I think the reason is that setup.iss file only specifies the UI operations for the very first installation, but when the same package being ran again the UI is for uninstall, so that rule doesn't match and -3 was returned.

I'm thinking adding logic into setup.iss to handle both the install and uninstall UI conditionally to simply just ignore the second install attempt so that 0 will be returned instead of -3 so the whole installation process will continue.

**Update:**

```
start /wait Setup.exe /s /f1C:\path\to\setup.iss with %errorlevel% = 0
```

`start /wait Setup.exe /s /f1C:\path\to\uninstall.iss with %errorlevel% = -3` but the program seems to be uninstalled completely.

Uninstall.iss:

```
[{1E0559A1-9644-40EF-B7B7-000000001386}-DlgOrder]
Dlg0={1E0559A1-9644-40EF-B7B7-000000001386}-MessageBox-0
Count=2
Dlg1={1E0559A1-9644-40EF-B7B7-000000001386}-SdFinishReboot-0
[{1E0559A1-9644-40EF-B7B7-000000001386}-MessageBox-0]
Result=6
[{1E0559A1-9644-40EF-B7B7-000000001386}-SdFinishReboot-0]
Result=1
BootOption=0
```

here,

```
[{1E0559A1-9644-40EF-B7B7-000000001386}-MessageBox-0]
    Result=6
```

doesn't seem to be a valid entry, because according to the manual MessageBox should only have Result of 1 which is the OK button, but here is 6. But this response file was recorded not manually generated.

Is it possible that this entry should be a custom dialog instead of a messagebox and should be treated as such and this is the cause of ResultCode=-3?

Thanks,